# TeXstudio - Go to command definition

Tags: texstudio

Is there an option in TeXstudio to get from a command to its definition?
(similar to Visual Studio's `F12` or PyCharm's `Ctrl+B`)

For example, I have the source line:

```
\input{other.tex}

The \equat{} is: $\varx + \vary = 0$
```

And in `other.tex` file I have:

```
\newcommand{\equat}{\text{Important Equation}}
\newcommand{\varx}{\text{$x$}}
\newcommand{\vary}{\text{$y$}}
```

And I want to navigate from `\equat{}`to its definition in `other.tex` file, preferably with keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I understand these are just examples, but they're completely wrong: you cannot do `\newcommand{\equation}` without getting errors; you cannot define commands such as `\var1` and `\var2`. And defining something as `\text{$x$}` is really wrong.

Comment: What @egreg is saying is true. However, to provide an answer to your question: If you hold Ctrl (maybe Command on Mac?) and click on a macro in your document, TeXstudio should take you to its definition.

Comment: @Gaussler that works! Thanks!

Comment: @egreg fixed the example so it works. However, why is `\text{$x$}` really wrong?

Comment: There is no advantage in being able to use `\varx` in both text and math modes. If you *really* want to (but you shouldn't), `\newcommand{\varx}{\ensuremath{x}}` would be the most efficient code. If you use your definition in math mode, TeX has to exit it, typeset four instances of the math mode `x` and use one of them.

Comment: I see, now I understand. Thanks @egreg!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, going to a command definition is possible by pressing `Ctrl` key and clicking the macro in the code.