# Creating a link to a previous item in the same document

Tags: moderncv, cv

In this template:

```
\section{Work Experience \newline}
\cventry{start-end_date}{worked at company A}{[list, of, stacks]}{}{}{\begin{itemize}       
        \item tech stack similar to previous freelance activity
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{start-end_date}{worked at compay B}{[another stack different from A above]}{}{}{\begin{itemize}
        \item did cool stuff
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{start-end_date}{freelancer}{[the same stack as company A (the first one)]}{}{}{\begin{itemize}
        \item did cool stuff
\end{itemize}}
```

how can you add a link to the item to a cventry. For example, clicking a link in the items list of the first cventry (company A) should go down to the third cventry (the one with the freelance work).

Is this doable?

I don't know how **cventry** and **item** are defined. Holding **Ctrl** and clicking them

as suggested here:

[TeXstudio - Go to command definition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/650713/texstudio-go-to-command-definition)

just highlights the pdf preview.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}  

\moderncvstyle{classic}                            
\moderncvcolor{black}  

\usepackage[defernumbers=true,backend=bibtex,sorting=ydnt,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{publications.bib}
\usepackage[top=1cm, left =0.5cm, right =1.2cm, bottom =1cm]{geometry}

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} 
\setlength{\makecvheadnamewidth}{10cm}

\name{\hspace{0.5cm}User \\ \indent  \hspace{0.5cm}Name}{}
\title{\hspace{0.5cm} Dev}     
\address{address}{Street}{country}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{-0.6cm}
\makecvtitle
\vspace{-0.7cm}

\section{Work exp \newline}
\cventry{start-end date}{Role}{[tech stack]}{}{}{\begin{itemize}        
        \item worked on stuff
\end{itemize}}
```

Comment: Can you provide a **full** minimal working example?

Comment: @NBur Done (added example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some `\label` and `\hyperref`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}

\name{\hspace{0.5cm}User \\ \indent  \hspace{0.5cm}Name}{}
\title{\hspace{0.5cm} Dev}
\address{address}{Street}{country}
\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pdfborder = 0 0 1,linkcolor=blue}}
\begin{document}
  \section{Work exp \newline}
  \cventry{start-end date\label{compA}}{Role}{[tech stack]}{}{}{\begin{enumerate}        
      \item worked on some stuff
      \item worked on stuff
  \end{enumerate}}
  \cventry{start-end date}{worked at compay B}{[another stack different from A above]}{}{}{\begin{enumerate}
      \item did cool stuff\label{stuff}
  \end{enumerate}}
  \cventry{start-end date}{freelancer}{[the same stack as company A (\hyperref[compA]{the first one})]}{}{}{\begin{enumerate}
      \item did cool stuff (see \hyperref[stuff]{here})
  \end{enumerate}}
\end{document}
```

I tweak the `hypersetup` to see the link (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44377/151808)

[image]